# Where can I get fish for my Ocelot in a superflat world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have finally tamed a ocelot! The only problem is that I have no more fish!

Do I really need to feed an ocelot? It is only a baby. If I do need to feed it, where can I find an ocean in a superflat world?

Comment: We need more detail than this. also try giving more info.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! We'd need your world generation settings in order to properly answer this. Could you edit your question and include them?

Answer (score 1):

There are no oceans in the basic superflat world, but you don't need to feed it like minecraft dogs, who need food to restore health. In other words, it will never starve. You couldn't make it grow though.

Comment: The only time you need fish is to make it breed, but again, with only one cat, that makes it redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an ocean. If you can get have two buckets worth of water, you can [create](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Water#Source_blocks) an arbitrarily big body of water yourself, just dig it (or build embankments) and use the water source duplication techniques to fill it.

Given sticks (in case of lack of trees obtainable as drops from witches) and string (obtainable from spiders) you can craft a fishing rod, and use it to [catch fish](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fishing) in your artificial pond. No fish mobs will spawn, but you'll still be able to catch 'generated' fish through the old (pre 1.13) mechanics.